# what is the use of this sign %<-% in r

Tags: r, keras

I am learning keras with r, and I am looking at this page for using Keras in classification,

https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/tutorial_basic_classification.html

but I do not quite understand what %<-% means

I have search %<-% in stackoverflow, but I did not find any answer.

```r
fashion_mnist <- dataset_fashion_mnist()

c(train_images, train_labels) %<-% fashion_mnist$train
c(test_images, test_labels) %<-% fashion_mnist$test
```

Comment: R lets you define your own infix operators in that format.  Try `help("%<-%")` or just print it bare at the REPL to see its source code, which I assume is defined in that package

Comment: I don't think the dupe target really answers the question though. It gives more info sure, but not about what the specific operator does.

Comment: Not exactly, but one could ask the same question about any custom infix operator.  I think the idea is once a person knows about R's custom infix operators they should be able to just use the normal help mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help page:

```
?keras::`%<-%`
```

> %<-% and %->% assign into the environment in which they are evaluated.
>
> [..]
>
> At its simplest, the name structure may be a single variable name, in
>   which case %<-% and %->% perform regular assignment, x %<-% list(1, 2,
>   3) or list(1, 2, 3) %->% x.

So, in this case, it's just like `x <- list(1,2,3)`. The neat trick is when you want to do multiple assignments:

> [..]
>
> To specify multiple variable names use a call to c(), for example c(x,
>   y, z) %<-% c(1, 2, 3).

So you can assign in one line to multiple objects multiple outputs:

```
# basic usage
c(a, b) %<-% list(0, 1)

a  # 0
b  # 1
```

This will be equal to:

```
a<-0
b<-1
```

In your example `fashion_mnist$train` it's an object (I guess a `list`) that has two elements `"train images"` and `"train labels"`, and so this one-liner lets you assign properly these two in the environment.

This behavior is similar to Python, which lets you do this "multiple-assignment" by default.